# HttpClientResponse Error while Listen Data

Tags: http, flutter, dart, httpclient

### Problem

I get response from `HttpClientResponse` After that trying to perform listen like:

```
//... your code
response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen( (data) {
   //... your code
})
//... your code
```

### Error(s)

```
The argument type 'Utf8Decoder' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer<Uint8List, dynamic>'
```

### Some Extra Detail(s)

- Flutter Commit at `4cd12fc8b`
- Previously it was working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This implementation is changed after fixing a bug in Stream handling.

Following is the changed request raised in Flutter community - https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36900

You can fix this issue with following changes

```
request.close().then((response){
  response.cast<List<int>>().transform(utf8.decoder).listen((content) {
        return content;
      });
});
```

For reference : https://github.com/dart-lang/co19/pull/384