# utf8.decoder not working after latest Flutter Upgrade

Tags: android, http, flutter, dart

The class APIPostRequest was wroking all fine until a flutter upgrade hit and it shows an error of "The argument type 'Utf8Decoder' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer'." while transforming HttpClientResponse's object into String using ...transform(utf8.decoder)...

```
class APIPostRequest {
  Future<String> apiRequest(String url, Map jsonMap) async {
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
    request.headers.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    request.headers
        .set('Authorization', "Bearer " + UserConstants.userAccessToken);
    request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)));
    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    httpClient.close();
    return reply;
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess it should work fine if you are on the `stable` channel

Comment: It was working fine just before the upgrades. Tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862020/httpclientresponse-error-while-listen-data but it seems it is changing the expected response in some other string values

Comment: I did not get you. Does that solution not work you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [corresponding breaking change announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-announce/LTe4SYU8-0Q):

> ### Error cases (and how to fix them):
>
> If you see the following errors in your code, here's what you do to fix them:
>
> - *Error*: "The argument type 'Utf8Decoder' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer'."
>
>   - *How to fix*: Use `StreamTransformer.bind(Stream)` instead of `Stream.transform(StreamTransformer)`.
>   - *Example*:
>
>     - *Before*: `foo.transform(utf8.decoder)...`
>     - *After*: `utf8.decoder.bind(foo)...`

Answer (score 3):

Comment `String reply = await utf8.decoder.bind(response).join();`

and use the following code :

```
//String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
String reply;
request.close().then((response){
response.cast<List<int>>().transform(utf8.decoder).listen((content) {
    print (content);
    reply = content;
});
```

Comment: This solution helped me thank you

Answer (score 0):

See below solution

```
class APIPostRequest {
    Future<String> apiRequest(String url, Map jsonMap) async {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
        request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
        request.headers.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
        request.headers
            .set('Authorization', "Bearer " + UserConstants.userAccessToken);
        request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)));
        HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
        String reply = await utf8.decoder.bind(response).join();
        httpClient.close();
        return reply;
    }
}
```